# Same rights for owner and group owner, but different result

Tags: permissions, chown

I have the user with the name sftpuser in the group sftpuser. `cat /etc/group | grep sftpuser` gives:

`sftpuser:x:1001:sftpuser`

I have the directory `html`, `ls -l` on the parent folder gives for the folder `html` the following:

`drwxrwsr-x+ 2 root sftpuser`

Reboot done.

If I connect to the server with FileZilla and the user sftpuser and enter the directory html, I can't create new files. I have the same issue with WinSCP (3 - permission denied). If I declare sftpuser as the owner, it works just fine. FileZilla shows under Owner/Group for the folder html "root 1001".

Just why? And btw. what does the plus at the end of the permission descriptor stand for?

Answer (score 2):

The `+` at the end of the permissions string indicates that the directory has an [Access Control List (ACL)](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Access_Control_Lists) applied to it.

It is likely that your ACL is somehow denying the user `sftpuser` write access to the directory.

To view the ACL for the `html` directory, use the command:

```sh
getfacl html
```

This should output something like the following:

```
# file: html
# owner: root
# group: sftpuser
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::r-x
```

The lines shown above are the defaults for a directory with the permission string `drwxrwsr-x`. Any additional lines are the ACL at work.

For instance, if the `getfacl` output was as follows:

```
# file: html
# owner: root
# group: sftpuser
# flags: -s-
user::rwx
user:sftpuser:r-x
group::rwx
mask::rwx
other::r-x
```

Then, because of the line `user:sftpuser:r-x`, the user `sftpuser` would explicitly be denied write access to the directory.

The above may not be your exact case, but perhaps some other ACL entry matches the user `sftpuser` and denies write access.

You can remove individual ACL entries by running, for example:

```sh
# replace "user:sftpuser" with the entry you want to remove, but omit the permissions part
setfacl -x user:sftpuser html
```

Or you can remove all entries (except the default ones for the user, group, and others) by running:

```sh
setfacl -b html
```

Comment: Thank you, I will check that. Since you gave a detailed answer, may I ask: Can I assume that ACL such as set with `setfacl` are always relevant under Linux or are they not that deeply implemented into the system? And where are they stored?

Comment: I believe the Linux kernel always checks ACLs for any file operation. As for where they are stored, the filesystem itself decides how to store that metadata. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/93508/405252